# Google API Maps, Remove Map or Hide it with layer

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to leave the markers and the city name, but have a black background? Either by removing the map or overlaying something to hide it?

I know this is an odd and seemingly stupid questions as it is a map, but for the purposes of a project I am working on this is required and I would just like to know if this is even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just put an opaque black overlay using the Google Maps API. But if you do that you will get some glitch when zooming/dezooming.

I think the best way is to customize the map colors and put everything in black.

See there : http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

- Be sure to select only `Geometry` in the `Element type` section
- And just put "lightness" to -100.

Comment: If i set lightness to -100 I cannot see town names though can I? Take London for example.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you wanted to see anything.  If you want to see the town names then you need to use a styled map, you should be able to find a way to make it look like you want, see the wizard in the answer and the documentation.  You will need to use the Google Maps API v3, which isn't in your tags.

Comment: @Max If you want to see the town names, instead of "All" in "Element type" section, just select "Geometry" (not Label, that's what you want to see). I edit my answer.